# Finding correlation between unequal group sizes in SPSS

Tags: correlation, spss

I  am working on correlating teacher factors with student achievement. How should I prepare the data set in SPSS for 130 teachers and 4000 student scores? I also have the same question with regression, should I input them as is or do I need to do something on my data set. I'm new with SPSS and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Clearly you have multiple students for each teacher.  Do you have multiple teachers for each student?

Comment: Yes, multiple students for each teacher but I don't think there are multiple teachers for each student. You see I'm working on secondary data and this is from an international assessment for student achievement.